# psycopg2 Ignore inserting row with null value

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, psycopg2

I'm populating a database from a .csv file and somewhere in my code I'm referring to a foreign key that might be invalid ( so when I'm going to select that id it returns null). At this point I want to log the row that returns null value and ignore insertion of that row but transaction don't stop and continue. How do I achieve this?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    insert_query = f"""insert into {table_name}
                (travel_date, train_id, delay)
                values ({row[0]},
                (select id from {train_table} where {train_table}.train_no={row[1]} limit 1),
                {row[2]});"""
    cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

Comment: 1) **Do not** use `f` strings(string interpolation) for parameter passing. The correct and safe way to do this is found here [Parameter Passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). 2) Your choices are either  a) Test that value before the insert and don't do the insert after capturing the id in say a list b) Run the `cursor.execute()` in a `try/except` and on the insert error capture the id and rollback the error.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for your advice. I changed the code and now using "%s" passing method. For the actual solution I chose first approach and tested id values and insert row when id is not null.